# Perl oneliner to extract regexp line by line

Tags: perl

I have a log file with entries like:

```
2014-06-10 10:31:53 [Thread-9] TRACE Class - logging message: Object [field1=field1 value, field2=field2 value, field3=field3, field4=[name, value], field5=field5, field6=field6]
```

I would like to format it to such output:

```
field2 value, [name value], field5
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed the field values and name can't contain commas.

```
perl -ne '/field2=([^,]*).*field4=\[([^,]*).*field5=([^,]*)/ and print "$1, [$2], $3\n"'
```